# How can I stack search criteria using & in a nested query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this index mapping with nested fields:

```
  "customerpropertieses": {
    "_parent": {
      "type": "customerprofile"
    },
    "_routing": {
      "required": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "parentId": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "properties": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "extentionPropertyId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "propertyName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to find customerpropertieses where `propertyName=criteria1 & value=value1 & propertyName=criteria2 & value=value2`

The query I'm generating by hand is this:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "properties.propertyName": {
                  "query": "criteria1 "
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "properties.value": {
                  "boost": 10.0,
                  "query": "value1"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "properties.propertyName": {
                  "query": "criteria2"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "properties.value": {
                  "boost": 10.0,
                  "query": "value2"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "path": "properties",
      "inner_hits": {
        "explain": false
      },
      "_name": "nested_properties"
    }
  }
}
```

I get 0 results back and I certainly have data with those characteristics. The search works fine when I look only `propertyName=criteria1 & value=value1` or with propertyName=criteria2 & value=value2'

The question is how can I stack search criteria using & in a nested query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the  following query. From the look of your query i take a guess you want to match documents which had two nested documents with values value1,criteria1 and value2,criteria2 in value and criteria field respectively.

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [{
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "match": {
                                    "properties.propertyName": {
                                        "query": "criteria2"
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "match": {
                                    "properties.value": {
                                        "boost": 10.0,
                                        "query": "value2"
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "properties",
                    "inner_hits": {
                        "explain": false
                    },
                    "_name": "nested_properties"
                }
            }, {
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "match": {
                                    "properties.propertyName": {
                                        "query": "criteria1 "
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "match": {
                                    "properties.value": {
                                        "boost": 10.0,
                                        "query": "value1"
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "properties",
                    "inner_hits": {
                        "explain": false
                    },
                    "_name": "nested_properties"
                }
            }]
        }

    }
}
```

I indexed the following document making the guess and modified the query
The Following document will match the query above

```
  {
      "parentId" : "3434",
      "properties" : [{
        "extentionPropertyId" : 24,
        "propertyName" : "criteria1",
        "value" : "value1"
      },{
        "extentionPropertyId" : 24,
        "propertyName" : "criteria2",
        "value" : "value2"
      }]
    }
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: umm perhaps I didn't explain it properly customerpropertieses.properties is a List[Tuple[propertyName, value]] in my C# code. I want the query to match multiple item in this list ie give me all customerpropertieses where propertyName=tomato and value=red AND propertyName=corn and value=yellow. Now this would return customerpropertieses which has 2 properties in the list: red tomato and yellow corn

Comment: yes, that's exactly this query is doing criteria2 value2 and criteria1 value1. I have added two nested must filters.

Comment: oh I see; so if I want to match on 4 criteria I need 4 nested queries. Correct?

Comment: yes, you will need four nested. I am glad this worked for you. Thanks